# On distinct integer set.

Tags: linear-diophantine-equations

All numbers here are integers. If $gcd(a,b)=1$ then if $(x_0,y_0)\neq(x_1,y_1)$ with $0<x_i<b$ and $0<y_i<a$ we have $ax_0+by_0\neq ax_1+by_1$.

Similarly is it true $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\neq(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ with $0<x_i<b$, $0<y_i<\min(a,b)$ and $0<z_i<a$ we will have $a^2x_0+aby_0+b^2z_0\neq a^2x_1+aby_1+b^2z_1$?

Comment: This is hard to read.  Why can't I take $x_0=b$, $y_0=0$, $x_1=0$, $y_1=a$?  Then it looks like we get $ab$ on both sides.  Or does $x_i\in (0,b)$ refer to the open interval $0<x_i<b$?  If so take $x_0=\frac b2$, $y_1=\frac a2$.

Comment: $0\notin(0,a)$.All numbers here are integers.

Comment: So your condition reads $0<x_i<b$ etc.?  But then it seems trivial: take a supposed counterexample and rewrite your equality as $a(x_0-x_1)=b(y_1-y_0)$.  Since $\gcd (a,b)=1$ we see that $a$ divides $y_1-y_0$ but that is plainly impossible.

Comment: what you state I have already written in first paragraph.

Comment: Still seems trivial.  rewrite to get $a^2(x_0-x_1)+ab(y_0-y_1)+b^2(z_0-z_1)=0$ so $b$ divides $x_0-x_1$ and $a$ divides $z_0-z_1$

Comment: oops ok......!!

Comment: @lulu should we have $0<x_i<b$, $0<y_i<\min(a,b)$ and $0<z_i<a$. Even $0\leq x_i\leq b$, $0\leq y_i\leq \min(a,b)$ and $0\leq z_i\leq a$ works right?

Comment: No...take $a=3,b=4$  and $\{x_0,y_0,z_0\}=\{4,1,0\}$ , $\{x_1,y_1,z_1\}=\{0,0,3\}$.  (there are infinitely many counterexamples of this form).

Comment: but if one of $0$ or $b$ is avoided possible? you are using both $4$ and $0$? may be avoiding $0$ will help?

Comment: Well, there are counterexamples of the form $\{x_0,y_0,z_0\}=\{X,b,0\}$, $\{x_1,y_1,z_1\}=\{X,0,a\}$ so you need to avoid those as well.  If you play around with the constraints I expect you can find some that work...surely, though, context should tell you what constraints you actually need?

Comment: @lulu yes but you are still using $0$. If you avoid $0$ may be you wont get match.

Comment: Well, the fact that, say, $b|(x_0-x_1)$ is very strong.  If you can block the solution $x_0-x_1=b$ then you quickly rule out everything non-trivial.

Comment: @luly ahha then $x_0=x_1=b$ not allowed then you wont get match even with $0$ allowed.

Comment: Not following.  You need at least one of $(x_0-x_1)$ and $(z_0-z_1)$ to be non-zero.  Divisibility then pretty much tells you what values they have to be...if you block those out by some constraint or other then there are no non-trivial solutions.

Comment: @lulu do you know this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805533/counting-solutions-to-equation-summing-to-0?

Comment: I'll take a look later.